# How to calculate image size for different devices dpi

Tags: android

I have a listview layout with images

It looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:id="@+id/listview_item_imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FAC308"
    android:id="@+id/listview_item_title"
    android:text="TITLE"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/listview_item_subtitle"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:text="SUBTITLE"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/orangeSeparator"
    android:src="@drawable/orangeseparator"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

If I run it on device with 720x1280 240dpi it looks like this

[image]

If I run it on device with 720x1280 320dpi it looks like this

[image]

I get images from the internet, so I cant prepare different versions.

How to make it look similar across all the devices ?

Comment: You can use fitCenter and Wrap_content in your imageview, or just take the image size and put it to the imageview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use fitXY [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html),

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

or you can also create different drawable resources from the original one, with Photoshop or any similar program

Comment: That will not respect aspect ratio, and he told the images are downloaded so he cannot prepare them.

Comment: The aspect ratio can be defined in the layout with the width and height, if he wants that the image appears in the same way on every device.  The alternative suggestion was to download the images manually for example through the browser and then resize them with Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

in your container you have

> android:layout_height="match_parent"

and in the image:

> android:layout_height="240dp"

you have to have the same height or 'wrap_content' for your container not to have those gaps.

you can also add to the imageview:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

another thing is that you can use specific library to handle loading of network images.

Answer (score 0):

You can look this article . Make your app  supporting different dpi variations and different screen types: [Supporting Different Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)